# large number of InnoDB tables plus SHOW TABLE STATUS

Tags: mysql, innodb

We've got several hundred InnoDB tables in a database, and we use phpMyAdmin to manage them. Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin does a `SHOW TABLE STATUS` query whenever the list of tables is shown, and this seems to dig into each InnoDB table to get an approximate row count.

This seems to lock up the entire database, which subsequently means all other queries to this (busy) database all queue up until the database hits the max users.

1. Can `SHOW TABLE STATUS` be sped up in a reasonable manner?
2. Can phpMyAdmin be easily modified to not do a full `SHOW TABLE STATUS` query, or at least not lock the entire database at once for it?

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` doesn't lock tables—at least, I've certainly never encountered it doing so.  Furthermore, the row count for InnoDB in `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is just an estimate, so it's definitely not doing a `COUNT(*)` or moral equivalent.  What do you get from a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` while the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is running?

One possibility to investigate: your `table_open_cache` might be too small, causing you to get stuck closing and re-opening many tables in the course of running your status query.

Comment: My understanding is that InnoDB gets its approximate row counts by diving into the various tables' files and seeking a few locations within it. Faster than `COUNT(*)` but still significant with lots of hefty tables. When `SHOW TABLE STATUS` runs, I see lots of queries that normally would be nearly instant sitting around waiting. Killing the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` lets them all execute normally.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the [`innodb_stats_on_metadata` setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata), which appears to do the trick. Disables InnoDB's diving into the indexes to get approximate counts.

Comment: By any chance, do you have innodb_file_per_table enabled?  If not, try enabling it (and dumping, dropping, and re-importing the tables).  I suspect that would allow the disk reads to be much more intelligent than they are when `ibdata1` is getting hit for everything.

Comment: @BMDan `innodb_file_per_table` is set to 1.

Comment: Are these databases actually in their own `.ibd`s?  What's the size of your `innodb_buffer_pool`?  How are `table_open_cache`, `open_files_limit`, and the sysctl `fs.file-max` set?  How much memory do you have under `Cached` in `free -m`?  What's your `vm.vfs_cache_pressure` set to?  Is your disk subsystem performant?  I'm beating so hard on this because generating table statistics should be very, very fast in the vast majority of cases; if it's not, that's at best a misconfiguration, because otherwise it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, all in their own .ibd file. innodb_buffer_pool_size=5662310400. table_open_cache=128. open_files_limit=5000. fs.file-max=766730. 6550 cached in free -m. vm.vfs_cache_pressure=100. No disk subsystem issues to our knowledge.

Comment: Your `table_open_cache` appears to be too small, but otherwise your settings seem reasonable, if a bit arbitrary (5400 MB buffer pool, rather than 5 GB even?).  Try bumping `table_open_cache` to 1536 and see what happens.

Comment: You didn't mention whether you were using 5.5, 5.1 with InnoDB plugin, or something older/nastier.  If using something older, you may need to adjust the `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size`.  Related question: Do you see anything in the mysql error log during `SHOW TABLE STATUS` runs?

Comment: `innodb_stats_on_metadata` is the right place to look for solving this issue.  It's a [well known one that's existed for years](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/12/03/innodb_stats_on_metadata-slow-queries-information_schema/).